# Why sometimes &nbsp; displays as a square?

Tags: html

page in question:
http://www.nyaii.com/news/news-id=10.html

I think the square that appears in my computer is some utf-8 characters so it might not be the same on other computers. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The HTML code of these squares are just `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

Comment: actualy, `&nbsp` is non-breakable white space and those squares are not recognised chars

Comment: I don't understand. This is just my question, &nbsp; is supposed to display a space, not a square. Are you suggesting there is something else inside the `td` other than &nbsp;?

Answer (score 1):

I believe typically that means that the character is not recognized by the font.

Comment: it also mean that user computer don't support that font. make sure you use  `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I do have this line in the HTML:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 0):

here are couple of thing i would check,

1. are you using a custom font, do that custom font support   ?
2. did you declear a charset in your meta?
3. instead of using `&nbsp;` why can't you use regular `space`?
4. are you using a data base, make sure you set the connection to utf-8 too.

Comment: this is a very basic html file without any database or custom font, and I do have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` in it.

Comment: Just use regular space

Comment: I'm not seeking to correct the site, I am just a little obssessed with why &nbsp; turns out to be a square.

Comment: your site, is poorly built, you should use css for the space for the table instead a new row of nothing-ness,  if you need help, you can get in contact with me, i am also in ny, also chinese.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I am just a webmaster, and the owner is contend with its current stage at this time so I really don't care.